# Change :hover on iPad So First Touch is Registered as onclick and :hover Functionailty Still Works

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

I'm porting over a web page to work on an iPad (since that is what the company uses). On the desktop I used :hover to navigate menus. On the iPad I need to be able to click on a menu item to expand the menu (which works just fine). I have added an onclick event that is supposed to display a button that allows collapsing the menu. The button is supposed to appear as soon as the menu is expanded, HOWEVER the click event isn't registered until the second click of the menu item, so the button doesn't initially appear. So here is the top navigation menu's hover. On the first touch on the list item this (:hover) works.

```
#nav li:hover {
background-color:#80CCFF;
color:black;
opacity:1;
}
#nav li:hover > ul.child {

top:39px; 
display:inline;
position:absolute;
text-align:left;
```

}

Here is the top of navigation html:

```
<ul id="nav">

    <input  id="button1" style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="button1class" name="Button1" type="button" value="Collapse Menu" onclick="hidebutton();return false;"/>

<li class="green"><a id="close" href="" onclick="showiframe(this.id); return false;">Development</a>
```

And here is a snippet of the javascript showiframe():

```
else {

    document.getElementById("theiframe").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "block";
}
```

To summarize, the onClick doesn't get called until the second click which I know is how Safari is supposed to work when it sees a :hover. What I want to do is write the code so there are no :hovers, everything works as if there were :hovers meaning the menu expands as needed, and the onclick is sensed on the first click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="nav">

    <input  id="button1" style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="button1class" name="Button1" type="button" value="Collapse Menu" onclick="hidebutton();return false;"/>

<li class="green"><a id="close" href="" onclick="showframe(this.id); return false;">Development</a>
```

try with this code

Comment: You didn't change anything from what I had.